# How do I update a text edit in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, textedit

Basically, I need to know how to insert a user inputted string into a text edit on my gui from within my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
   String str = "this is a text";
   EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
   editText.setText(str, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

You can use any string in `String` object.

Comment: My question was kind of ambiguous. I need to be able to putba string compiled in my code into a text edit on the gui